# How get file names via JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How do we get file names?:

```
<input type="file" multiple />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look in the files property.

[tutorial, full documentation and sample code here](http://help.dottoro.com/ljxenmhs.php)